# Editing a SQLAlchemy entry & committing the update changes the output of Model method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a Flask application that uses SQLAlchemy, I have declared a `Deliverymen` model with some methods, properties and class methods. One of them, `get_own_data(self)` builds and returns a dictionary with only the relevant information that the end user needs (the full Model declaration is down below):

```py
def get_own_data(self):
        own_data = {
            key: value
            for (key, value) in vars(self).items()

            # Exclude the following keys
            if key != "_sa_instance_state" and key != "moto_placa"
        }
        
        # Add this key, which isn't found in 'vars(self)' as it is a class property
        own_data["moto_placa_upper"] = self.moto_placa

        return own_data
```

The key-pair defined at has to be defined like that due to form handling & a property setter that takes user input and turns the *placa (or license plate)* into  upper case. That property and its setter are also available below.

When I try to edit an existing entry and then I commit the changes, the `get_own_data` method **only** returns the last key-pair defined, as below:

```py
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 23 2022, 23:05:40) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
App: app [development]
Instance: /home/daniel/Documents/work/breakfast4you/reportes/backend/instance
>>> d = Deliveryman.query.first()
>>> d.get_own_data()
{'user_id': 9, 'nombre': 'James Bond', 'telefono': '1234567890', 'status': 1, 'arp': 'Protección', 'tipo_cuenta': 'Ahorros', 'direccion': 'Dirección de prueba', 'id': 1, 'gov_id': '1234789845', 'eps': 'Sanitas', 'moto_marca': 'AKT', 'nombre_banco': 'Davivienda', 'num_cuenta': '1234567890', 'moto_placa_upper': 'BND 007'}
>>> d.nombre = "Carlos"
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> d.get_own_data()
{'moto_placa_upper': 'BND 007'}
```

Confusingly, if after committing the changes I access any of the object properties and then run `d.get_own_data()`... it works again!

```py
>>> d.nombre
'Carlos'
>>> d.get_own_data()
{'nombre': 'Carlos', 'tipo_cuenta': 'Ahorros', 'status': 1, 'user_id': 9, 'arp': 'Protección', 'telefono': '1234567890', 'direccion': 'Dirección de prueba', 'num_cuenta': '1234567890', 'eps': 'Sanitas', 'nombre_banco': 'Davivienda', 'id': 1, 'gov_id': '1234789845', 'moto_marca': 'AKT', 'moto_placa_upper': 'BND 007'}
```

This is the model declaration:

```py
class Deliveryman(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "delivery_men"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("users.id"), index=True, unique=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, index=True)
    direccion = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    telefono = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    gov_id = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)
    eps = db.Column(db.String(150))
    arp = db.Column(db.String(150))
    moto_marca = db.Column(db.String(20))
    moto_placa = db.Column(db.String(7))
    nombre_banco = db.Column(db.String(20))
    tipo_cuenta = db.Column(db.String(20))
    num_cuenta = db.Column(db.String(30))

    @property
    def moto_placa_upper(self):
        return self.moto_placa

    @moto_placa_upper.setter
    def moto_placa_upper(self, placa):
        if placa is None:
            pass
        else:
            self.moto_placa = placa.upper()

    # Another method that is irrelevant to this question

    def get_own_data(self):
        own_data = {
            key: value
            for (key, value) in vars(self).items()
            if key != "_sa_instance_state" and key != "moto_placa"
        }

        own_data["moto_placa_upper"] = self.moto_placa

        return own_data

    # Class methods irrelevant to this question
```

What could cause this issue? I'm not an expert on OOP and I have the feeling that there's a bug in my method and property declarations, but I cannot point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that SQLAlchemy [expires](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring) objects in the session on commit.  Expiry removes all the persisted attributes from a persisted object's `__dict__`, so there is nothing to iterate over when `get_own_data` is called.

There are a few ways around this:

1. Refresh the object by calling `db.session.refresh(obj)` before calling `get_own_data`; this will trigger a `SELECT` to fetch the data.
2. Disable expiry on commit by passing `session_options={'expire_on_commit': False}` when creating the `SQLAlchemy` (`db`) object.  This is a global setting, and you risk your instances containing stale data, as in this case a `SELECT` is *not* emitted.
3. Rather than iterating over `vars`, iterate over the column names and get the values using `getattr`; as with refreshing, this will trigger a `SELECT`.

   ```py
   from sqlalchemy import inspect
   ...
       def get_own_data(self):
           insp = inspect(self)
           own_data = {
               key: getattr(self, key)
               for key in insp.mapper.columns.keys()

               # Exclude the following keys
               if  key != "moto_placa"
           }

           # Add this key, which isn't found in 'vars(self)' as it is a class property
           own_data["moto_placa_upper"] = self.moto_placa
           return own_data
   ```

Comment: I decided to go with the third option you provided, as it is an improvement over using `vars` and I was actually some time ago looking for a way to get column names. This fixed my issue, thank you very much.